# Clustering objects with a distance matrix

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there are several objects: o1, o2, o3...

And there's a distance/dissimilarity matrix D containing distance for **each pair** of the objects.

e.g. Dij is the distance/dissimilarity between oi and oj.

How to cluster these objects into groups so that:

Distance between each pair of objects in each group is smaller than a predefined threshold value.

Comment: Do you know the number of groups?

Comment: @adrianN We can assume the number of groups. Btw, based on my investigation, the number of groups/clusters is a big assumption/obstacle of many clustering algorithms.

Comment: Could the clusters be overlapping?

Comment: @vefthym no, there should be no overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. Form a graph where two points are connected if and only if the distance is no more than the threshold.
2. Find the largest groups of points in the graph such that, for each group, every group member has an edge to every other group member.

The catch with this is step (2) - it is [the clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), and is NP-complete.

Here's what you could do instead:

1. Cluster the points by [complete-linkage clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering), for which the second algorithm mentioned there, CLINK, has cost O(N²).
2. Stop the algorithm when the distance between clusters formed goes over the threshold, or walk down the tree so that clusters are the sub-trees with edges above the threshold above then and below the threshold below them.

With complete-linkage clustering, the distance between two clusters is the largest distance between any two points, one from each cluster, so if you join two clusters formed in this way at distance d to form a merged cluster, every pair of points in the merged cluster must be at most distance d from each other.

Since I presume that I have not just solved an NP-complete problem in time O(N²) (which would mean that P = NP, the proving/disproving of which [is unlikely to be this easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)), this second method will not necessarily provide as neat a clustering as the first one - but I haven't thought through this thoroughly enough to know exactly what the trade-offs are.

Comment: I think instead of finding just a clique, you want to find a minimum clique cover. It's not easier unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

1. Given a graph G, cluster any 2 vertices with `Distance(a,b) < threshold` and this is an initial solution\state
2. Enhance\Optimize this solution by making optimal merges

This approach is not optimal, but it's complete, and it comes with a low Time complexity.

```
Time = T(Step 1) + T(Step 2)

T(Step 1) ~ V + V/2 + V/4 + .. + 1 = 2V = O(V)

T(Step 2) ~ 1/c V^2 = O(V^2)

Time ~ 2V + 1/c V^2 = O(V) + O((^2) = O(V^2)
```

Comment: Please, clarify what is V, what is c, what is optimal merges, for a more complete and easier-to-understand answer.

Comment: @vefthym `V` is number of vertices, `c` is a constant, the analysis is theoretical, and `optimal merges` are series of merges that lead to minimize number of clusters overall

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the triangle inequality holds (i.e. o1, o2, ... are elements of a metric space (O,d)), then [canopy clustering](http://www.kamalnigam.com/papers/canopy-kdd00.pdf) should work.

The logic of canopy clustering is the following:

1. Pick a random object o from the initial set O.
2. Create for o, a new canopy Co and add to Co all objects i s.t. d(o,i) < T1.
3. Remove from O all objects j, s.t. d(o,j) < T2.
4. Repeat until O is empty.

T1 and T2 are two threshold values, where T2 < T1. Now, since triangle inequality holds, we know that for each pair of objects `oi`, `oj` in a cluster `Col` with center `ol`: `d(oi,oj) <= d(ol, oi) + d(ol, oj) < 2T1`.

Note that canopy clustering produces **overlapping clusters**, i.e. an object could be placed in more than one clusters. Note also that the number of generated clusters is not predefined.